# getting 403 Forbidden nginx with rails, puma, and server blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, puma

First time trying to deploy an app with rails - I'm trying to get a rails app running which is currently giving me a 403. I'm using ubuntu and nginx. I have two server blocks setup which I tested first with node apps which ran fine, and now one domain runs fine as a node app, but I'm trying to setup the other as a rails app which is giving the 403.

I used a combination of these two tutorials:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

I tried setting `755` permision in my `/home/deploy` dir and `/var/www/`, but no luck.

Other guesses -

- something to do with the `index index.html index.htm` ?
- something to do with the `default_server deferred;` in my nginx.conf (though I tried removing and no affect)

Here are my relevant files, which may be at fault, let me know if others are of help -

rails app, one in question: `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/centers`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /home/deploy/apps/mll/current/public;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name myrailssite.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

node app, works as intended at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nodeapp`

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www/nodeapp/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name 162.243.199.170;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/mll/shared/tmp/sockets/mll-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  server_name myrailssite.com;

  root /home/deploy/apps/mll/current/public;
  access_log /home/deploy/apps/mll/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/apps/mll/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://mll-puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Permissions:

```
deploy@banana:/usr/bin$ namei -l /var/www/centers/
f: /var/www/centers/
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root var
drwxr-xr-x root root www
drwxrwxr-x root root centers


deploy@banana:/usr/bin$ namei -l /home/deploy/apps/mll/current/public/
f: /home/deploy/apps/mll/current/public/
drwxr-xr-x root   root   /
drwxr-xr-x root   root   home
drwxr-xr-x deploy deploy deploy
drwxr-xr-x deploy deploy apps
drwxr-xr-x deploy deploy mll
lrwxrwxrwx deploy deploy current -> /home/deploy/apps/mll/releases/20160415005003
drwxr-xr-x root   root     /
drwxr-xr-x root   root     home
drwxr-xr-x deploy deploy   deploy
drwxr-xr-x deploy deploy   apps
drwxr-xr-x deploy deploy   mll
drwxr-xr-x deploy deploy   releases
drwxrwxr-x deploy deploy   20160415005003
drwxrwxr-x deploy deploy public
```

Comment: You have two server blocks with the same `server_name`. You also have two server blocks marked as `default_server`. So I am unclear as to which server block is expected to be servicing the request. Perhaps you should review your [server names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

Comment: where are you seeing the same server_name? The node app is `162.243.199.170` (the default as marked in the sites-enabled file) and the rails app is `myrailssite.com`. As I'm looking closer though now I see that I only have my `myrailssite.com` in my nginx.conf, though I'm unsure how to proceed/how that file should be filled in.

Comment: `nginx.conf` is the main file - start from there. The files in sites-enabled are included into `nginx.conf` (assuming you have something like `include sites-enabled/*` in your `nginx.conf` file).

Comment: thank you for noticing that issue, that was it! I didn't realize how these pieces fit together. I just removed those extra server settings from the `nginx.conf` and put them in my `sites-enabled` and now it's working. I should have  found and read this first -> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-nginx-web-server-on-a-virtual-private-server that was helpful

Answer (score -3):

I have also encountered the same issue with my application https://www.wiki11.com.

Your issue is coming because nginx is trying to search for `index.html` file into `/home/deploy/apps/mll/current/public` which is not present there. 
In order to fix, you will need to add passenger with your nginx.

Instructions to follow.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates
```

Add Passenger APT repository

```
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger xenial main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'
sudo apt-get update
```

Install passenger and nginx

```
sudo apt-get install -y nginx-extras passenger
```

Now start nginx webserver.

```
sudo service nginx start
```

Next, we need to update the Nginx configuration to point Passenger to the version of Ruby that we're using.

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And add or uncomment

```
include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;
```

Save and close nginx.conf. Then open `/etc/nginx/passenger.conf`

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/passenger.conf
```

If you are using .rbenv, then

```
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
```

Or if you are using rvm, then

```
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.5.0/ruby;
```

Or if you are using system ruby, then

```
passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
```

Next, restart nginx server

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Add `passenger_enabled on;` into your site-enabled/centers or site-enabled/nodeapp file.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /home/deploy/apps/mll/current/public;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name myrailssite.com;
        passenger_enabled on;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Restart nginx server again, `sudo service nginx restart`. Hopefully it should work.

For more details, follow,
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/xenial/

Comment: He was asking with Puma not using Passenger